# New Graphing Calculator 3D Stackexchange proposal is looking for people to register for a private beta

Tags: discussion

The graphing calculator 3d SE proposal has reached the commitment phase, where it needs 200 people to register for a private beta. Although it already has 194 members, only 12 of them have the necessary 200+ reputation needed. There is great enthusiasm for this site but most members are new students with no prior StackExchange accounts/reputations. Your help is pushing the site over the finish is appreciated. If you are at all interested, please sign up at:

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120787/graphing-calculator-3d

Comment: The proposal has now over 200 committers but still missing high-reputation committers. Please join if you have 200+ reputation.

Answer (score 2):

(The proposal was closed on May 30, 2019.)